# a python-telegram-bot Unsupported url protocol

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, pytube

So, I was Trying To Create a Telegram Bot That By Using The PyTube Moudle, Will Download The Video To My Computer And Then Send It To The User By The send_document Function.

My Problem Is When I Need To Send The Video, I Get This Error:

```
telegram.error.BadRequest: Invalid file http url specified: unsupported url protocol
```

I've Tried It On a Regular Text File And Got The Same Results.

I Assume It's Because The Url of The File Is Breaking Some Rules of How It Should Look Like, But I Don't Know How To Fix It...

Also Here Is My Code:

```
import telegram.ext
import telegram
from telegram.ext.messagehandler import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext.commandhandler import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters
import time
import pytube
import os

with open('C:/Users/EvilTwin/Desktop/stuff/Python/API/Telegram/Download Youtube Videos Bot/token.txt')as file:
    API_KEY = file.read()


updater = telegram.ext.Updater(token=API_KEY, use_context=True)


def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(f'Hello {update.effective_user.first_name}, I\'m Roee\'s Video Downloader!')
    time.sleep(1)
    update.message.reply_text(    
    f'''
To Download Videos Please Enter:
/download + Video URL  + Format
    
    ''')

def download(update, context):
    URL = context.args[0]
    FORMAT = context.args[1]
    VIDEO = pytube.YouTube(URL)
    FILE = VIDEO.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension=FORMAT).order_by('resolution').desc().first() 
    VD = 'C:/Users/EvilTwin/Desktop/stuff/Python/API/Telegram/Download Youtube Videos Bot/Videos'
    FILE.download(VD)
    banned = ['/', '/-\\', ':', '?', '!', '*', '>', '<', '"', '|']
    for ban in  banned:
        VIDEO.title = VIDEO.title.replace(ban, '')
    time.sleep(1)
    DOC = f'{VD}/{VIDEO.title}.{FORMAT}'
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    context.bot.send_document(chat_id = chat_id ,document=DOC, filename = f'video.{FORMAT}')
    os.remove(DOC)



updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('download', download))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

If Anyone Knows How To Fix It Please Help Me....

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `url` means string which starts with `https://`, `http://` and for local files `file://` - this values describe `"protocol"`. And your error shows that you used `unsupported url protocol`

Comment: you didn't show FULL error message so it is hard to say what is the problem. And don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides, it can work correctly on our computers. You have to add all details in question (not in comments). Error should show you in which line you have problem and first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables in this line - it can explain what can make problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local file you have to use `file object` (`file handler`) instead of `file name`
so you have to open it `document=open(DOC, 'rb')`

```
context.bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=open(DOC, 'rb'), filename=f'video.{FORMAT}')
```

---

Documentation shows also that you can use `pathlib.Path` or `bytes` (so it needs to read it `document=open(DOC, 'rb').read()`)  but I didn't test it.

See doc: [send_document()](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_document)